# get input from vba-Excel to batch script

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

assume that if i have value at cell C9, sheet1
down here is the code that i use for run .bat script from VBA

```
> Blockquote

Fileset = Sheet1.Range("C9")

txtFpath = Sheet1.Range("C7").Value
FilePath = txtFpath & "\res.bat"

ChDrive "D"
RSP = Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC"), vbNormalFocus)
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "CD " & txtFpath & "{ENTER}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "start " & FilePath & "{ENTER}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "exit " & "{ENTER}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "exit " & "{ENTER}", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "exit " & "{ENTER}", True


> Blockquote
```

and this is  res.bat that i will use

> Blockquote

```
@echo off
>summary.txt (
  for %%F in (*chkpackage.log) do findstr /l ###FileSet### "%%F" nul||echo %%F:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A
)
```

> Blockquote

my question is how do i going to put that value from c9 into ### Fileset ### in the bat file

thank you for your time and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [parameter](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php) in the batch file to easily send the value of range "C9".

**VBA code adding the parameter**

```
SendKeys "start " & FilePath & " " & FileSet & "{ENTER}", True
```

**Batch with with parameter**

```
@echo off
>summary.txt (
  for %%F in (*chkpackage.log) do findstr /l %1 "%%F" nul||echo %%F:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A:N/A
)
```

**EDIT:** If the value of C9 has any blank spaces you'll need to add quotations around the parameter or it will only take the first word (Hopefully someone could suggest a much better way though!)

Comment: can u explain a little bit more i want to know that "%1" what does it stand for

(i'm new to coding sorry)

Comment: "%1" is the first command line paramater 'sent' to the batch file. Read more here about batch file paramaters: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php